# How do I save to a text file the Values from a List<long>?

Tags: c#

Im doing this to create the file and save to it:

```
w = new StreamWriter(_outputDir + "\\" + averagesListTextFileDirectory + "\\" + averagesListTextFile + ".txt", false, Encoding.ASCII);
w.WriteLine("DANNY VIDEO META DATA\r\nFORMAT VERSION:1.00\r\nSOURCE: " + "<" + averagesListTextFile + ">" + "\r\nDATA: ");

for (int i = 0; i < averages.Count; i++)
{
    w.WriteLine(averages[i]);
}
w.WriteLine("DATA");
w.Close();
```

But now i want to save to the file the values from a List wich in each index have another array of values. Like:

> [0] 123 33 44 55 66...
>   [1] 33 44 565 66...

In each index there are 256 values.

I want the text file to look like that after DATA:
The next line will be something like:

> Frame Number 1: 123 33 44 55 66
>   Frame Number 2: 33 44 565 66

So each line will be with 256 values.

This format.

Now the format of the file is like this:

> DANNY VIDEO META DATA
>   FORMAT VERSION:1.00
>   SOURCE: 
>   DATA:
>   15.1199916409607
>   13.7612831147295
>   13.746730806327
>   13.2768227559145

Now i want to make that when i read the values from the List the format will be like this:

> DANNY VIDEO META DATA
>   FORMAT VERSION:1.00
>   SOURCE: 
>   DATA:
>
> Frame Number 1: 123 33 44 55 66
>   Frame Number 2: 33 44 565 66

The question is how do i read the List that each index contain the 256 values and how do i write it to the text file ?

This is how i tried to do it:

```
private void WriteHistograms() // For automatic mode only for now
        {
            HistogramsFile = new StreamWriter(_outputDir + "\\" + averagesListTextFileDirectory + "\\"  + "Histograms.txt", false, Encoding.ASCII);
            HistogramsFile.WriteLine("DANNY VIDEO META DATA\r\nFORMAT VERSION:1.00\r\nSOURCE: " + "<" + averagesListTextFile + ">" + "\r\nDATA: ");
            foreach (long[] array in Histograms)
            {
                foreach (long value in array)
                {
                  frameNumber++;
                  HistogramsFile.WriteLine("Frame Number " + frameNumber + " : " + value);                      

                }
            }
            HistogramsFile.WriteLine("DATA");
            HistogramsFile.Close();
```

The result is a 25MB file size ! And here is example of the text file format:

```
DANNY VIDEO META DATA
FORMAT VERSION:1.00
SOURCE: <MVI_2483.AVI_Automatic>
DATA: 
Frame Number 1 : 5977
Frame Number 2 : 40775
Frame Number 3 : 174395
Frame Number 4 : 305855
Frame Number 5 : 265805
Frame Number 6 : 212232
Frame Number 7 : 153333
Frame Number 8 : 99743
Frame Number 9 : 62334
Frame Number 10 : 41018
Frame Number 11 : 27381
Frame Number 12 : 21403
Frame Number 13 : 18324
```

In the end i see Frame Numbers:

```
Frame Number 973822 : 666
Frame Number 973823 : 1118
Frame Number 973824 : 0
```

Now sure why the last one is 0 and why 973824 frames while in fact there were about 3800 frames only.

So the file size is logic 25MB ? And format i wanted it to be is like:

Frame Number 1: 33 44 55 66 77 88 ......( 256 values in this line )
Frame Number 2: 22 33 12 3 44 55 .......( 256 values in this line )

And so on.

The List Histograms is type of  wich in every index there are 256 indexs in each one a number:

[0] have: [1] 23 [2] 22 [3] 44 and so on 
[1] have: [1] 12 [2] 13 [3] 21 and so on

So whats wrong ?

Comment: Please revisit the formatting of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a nested for loop in your original one:

```
foreach(long[] array in averages)
{

     foreach(long value in array)
     {
          w.WriteLine(value);
     }
}
```

This will allow you to iterate over your List of arrays. In general you would follow this type of loop for most 2 dimensional data structures.

**Edit:** If you want to print out each array on a seperate line you will need to modify the loop as follows:

```
int frameNumber = 1;
foreach(long[] array in averages)
{
     w.WriteLine("Frame Number " + frameNumber + " : ");
     frameNumber++;

     foreach(long value in array)
     {
          w.Write(value).Write(' ');
     }
}
```

This will produce the following:

```
Frame Number 1 : 10 15235 198 65439 24098...
Frame Number 2 : 10232 135 45619 895649 4598...
...
Frame Number N : 987 651 654 968498 21654...
```

Comment: I tried it tkeE2306 but im getting text file size of 25mb and not the format i wanted. I will update my question now !

Comment: See my edits...youi should be able to use that or modify it slightly for your needs